# jQuery mobile touchswipe failure after second pageinit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a site where I am using jQuery mobile. I use paginit to instantiate the touchswipe jQuery plugin. If I go from the page it is instantiated('Home') to another page (let's say 'About') back to Home it fails. In all other cases it works.

Breaks anytime starting from the page where pageinit triggers it:
Home > About > Home

Works any other time on multiple pageinit:
About > Home > Info > Home > About > Home

NOTE:::
I even changed all the names of the functions in touchswipe just in case.

Comment: What does the event binding code look like? What site structure are you using (multi-page or single-page template)?

Comment: I resolved the issue. The mobile site went to /directory and /directory/. jQuery mobile did not recognize these as the same so I believe it may have binded events to the first seen version of the page.

Comment: There is more info on how jQuery Mobile handles navigation here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html